# Does it matter who I pick to be on my team?

Tags: mario-sonic-london-2012

When you are playing Medley Matches, you need to pick 5 different team members, one from each of these categories:

- Heroes (Sonic, Tails, Mario, or Luigi)
- Girls (Amy, Peach, Daisy, or Blaze)
- Tricksters (Wario, Waluigi, Dr. Eggman, or Metal Sonic)
- Wild Ones (Knuckles, Bowser, Donkey Kong, or Vector)
- Challengers (Yoshi, Shadow, Bowser Jr, or SIlver)

Does it matter who I pick? Are certain characters better for certain events? Or is it a purely aesthetic choice?

Answer (score 2):

If you are playing on the Wii console, SEGA has provided character stat sheets detailing the different speeds, acceleration, stamina, etc. of each playable character. You can find the breakdown at the game website [here](http://www.olympicvideogames.com/mario-and-sonic-london-2012/#/Characters). You can look over the stats and determine which characters will be best for the different events you may encounter during the game play.

For instance, Yoshi has great acceleration speed, but only moderate stamina. He would perform best under sprinting circumstances. However, someone like Vector may be better for long distance events, or events that last a longer duration, because of his high stamina.

Comment: I am playing the 3DS version. Do you know if the stats are similar?

Comment: I have not played the 3DS version. The stats do state that they are only for the Wii. Since the 3DS version just released it may be difficult to know if this carries over.

Comment: I will keep an eye on the site, and hopefully they will update the information. :)